# Dynamic class + variables in VueJS / Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, variables, dynamic, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add dynamic variables (props) on a Tailwind class but something is wrong :

```
:class="`w-${percent}/12: ${show}`"
```

This is the output of this code :

```
<div class="w-0 h-2 transition-all duration-1000 ease-out bg-indigo-600 rounded-lg w-11/12: true"></div>
```

I don't understand why ':true' is added.

Thanks for your help.

Nb: https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: when true is gone do you get what you want ?

Comment: If i delete : ${show} yes but I need this to make the transition work (the value of show depend on scroll position).

Comment: If i use v-if=‘show’ for ex it will work but without the wanted transition.

Comment: i am sorry i am not familiar with tailwind, i am trying to understand what do you want to see in $show ? just show ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you use template literals which returns the `string`. So `show` is boolean `true` and it returns `"true"` as a string.

If you want to toggle class according to `show` variable, you must use `object` way.

```
<div
  class="w-0 h-2 transition-all duration-1000 ease-out bg-indigo-600 rounded-lg"
  :class="{ [`w-${percent}/12`]: show }"
>
  YOUR CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use interpolated class names with tailwind. Always use e.g. `w-8/12` over `w-{percent}/12`: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names